# Python DataFrame - Update one data-frame column from another based on condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working on one of the Data-Science competition, and stuck with one of the issue, where I have to update the value in original data-frame based on some condition from another data-frame.
I tired some code, but no luck.
Below is the detail...

Appreciate any advice.

## Ask is : Update the column "FIELD_1" as 2 if the CNT is more than 200 in new_df; 1 when the CNT is >100 and <200; 0 when CNT <100.

Code :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'FIELD_1': ['f710fca39', '1fd0233cd', '005dd4ce3', '5331f98fb', '005dd4ce3', 'f710fca39', 'eb0004a0b'], 
                         'B': [400        , 500        , 600        , 700        , 800        , 900        , 111]})
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'CNT': [225, 150, 80, 230],'ID': ['f710fca39', '1fd0233cd', '5331f98fb', '005dd4ce3']})
new_df.set_index('ID', inplace=  True)
print(df)
print(new_df)
#df.loc[df['FIELD_1'].isin(new_df.index ),'FIELD_1']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'FIELD_1': ['f710fca39', '1fd0233cd', '005dd4ce3', '5331f98fb', '005dd4ce3', 'f710fca39', 'eb0004a0b'], 
                         'B': [400        , 500        , 600        , 700        , 800        , 900        , 111]})
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'CNT': [225, 150, 80, 230],
                       'ID': ['f710fca39', '1fd0233cd', '5331f98fb', '005dd4ce3']})

df_ = df.copy()
df_=df_.rename(columns={"FIELD_1":"ID"})
mer = pd.merge(df_,new_df,how="left",on=["ID"])
def f(x):
    if pd.isnull(x):
        return np.nan
    elif x>200:
        return 1
    elif x<100:
        return 0
    else:
        return 2
mer["FIELD_1"]= mer.CNT.apply(lambda x: f(x))
mer=mer.drop(columns=["ID","CNT"])
```